Jacobian matrix from mass action kinetic ODE network
I have an ODE system consisting of >1000 equations for which I would like to obtain the Jacobian matrix. For simplicity, let's consider the following example:
X1 --> X2 + X3 (on1)
X1 + X2 --> X1 (off1)
X3 --> X4 + X5 (on2)
X4 + X5 --> X3 (off2)

Assuming mass-action kinetics, the derivative $\frac{dX}{dT}$ can be calculated using the following expression
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = (B-A)^T K x^A
$$
$A$ $(r,s)$ denotes the coefficients of reactants for each species $s$ in each reaction $r$. Similarly, $B$ denotes the coefficients of products:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \end{pmatrix};
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$(B-A)^T$ is the stochiometry matrix, $K$ is the diagonal matrix with rates (on1, off1, on2, off2) and $x^A$ is the vector-matrix exponentiation of states $x$ by reactant coefficients $A$, which is calculated as follows:
$$
x^A = \begin{pmatrix}
X1^1 X2^0 X3^0 X4^0 X5^0 \\ 
X1^0 X2^1 X3^1 X4^0 X5^0 \\
X1^0 X2^0 X3^1 X4^0 X5^0 \\
X1^0 X2^0 X3^0 X4^1 X5^1 \end{pmatrix};
x^A = \begin{pmatrix} X1 \\ X2 X3 \\ X3 \\ X4 X5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This takes care of the non-linear aspect of the equation and can be interpreted as matrix multiplication, with building the product of components instead of summing them. If anyone has a suggestion of how to formulate this in a more clean way please let me know.
Finally:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \begin{pmatrix} -1&1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&-1&1 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} on1 X1 \\ off1 X2 X3 \\ on2 X3 \\ off2 X4 X5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Which would result in
dX1/dt = -on1 X1 + off1 X2 X3
dX2/dt = on1 X1 - off1 X2 X3
dX3/dt = on1 X1 - off1 X2 X3 - on2 X3 + off2 X4 X5
dX4/dt = on2 X3 - off2 X4 X5
dX5/dt = on2 X3 - off2 X4 X5

I would like to get the Jacobian matrix $J$ in a similar matrix formulation as the derivative $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Does anyone know how to do this?
The resulting Jacobian $J$ should be:
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
-on1 & off1 X3 & off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
on1 & -off1 X3 & -off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
on1 & -off1 X3 & -off1 X2 - on2 & off2 X5 & off2 X4\\
0 & 0 & on2 & -off2 X5 & -off2 X4 \\
0 & 0 & on2 & -off2 X5 & -off2 X4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Your definition of $x^A$ makes no sense. Can you try to write you system into a sum of linear and quadratic components instead of defining vectors containing both? This will make computing the Jacobian much easier

Thank you @whpowell96 for the suggestion. I added a more detailed explanation of how $x^A$ is calculated.

So you have $\dot x = F(x)=S,T(x)$ with $T=x^A$ the monomial terms in the equations. Then the Jacobian is $\partial_x F(x)=S,T'(x)$ with $T'(x)$ the Jaobian of $T$. That should be easy to implement?

Thank you @LutzLehmann, that was indeed the missing puzzle piece! I will post an elaborated answer now:)

Perhaps a better way to write the unusual power function is to use standard functions applied elementwise to vector arguments, i.e. $$x^A = \exp(A,\log(x))$$ And this translates directly into Julia as $;$ exp.(A*log.(x))

thank you @greg that is indeed much more intuitive:)

To follow up on my comment
Denote the unusual power function by $y=x^A$ and calculate the differentials of the elementwise functions
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
w &= \log(x) &\qiq dw = dx \oslash x \\
y &= \exp(Aw) &\qiq dy = y\odot(A\,dw) \\
}$$
Hadamard multiplication and division can be replaced with ordinary matrix multiplication and inversion by using diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) &\qiq dw = X^{-1}\,dx \\
Y &= {\rm Diag}(y) &\qiq dy = Y(A\,dw) \,=\, YAX^{-1}\,dx \\
}$$
Rearranging that last expression yields the gradient of $y$ wrt $x$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= YAX^{-1} \\
}$$
Since the matrices
$$\eqalign{
K &= {\rm Diag}(\,on_1,\;off_1,\;on_2,\;off_2\,) \\
S &= (B-A)^T \\ 
}$$
are constants, the Jacobian of the $\sf ODE\,$ is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\,(SKy)}{\partial x} &= SKYAX^{-1} \\
}$$
When multiplied out, this reproduces the given Jacobian.

Answer:
Thank you to @LutzLehmann for the suggestion, which pointed me to the solution.
The Jacobian can be split into two parts:
$$
J = S T'(x)
$$
with $S = (B-A)^T$ (the stochiometry matrix) and $T'(x)$ being the Jacobian of the non-linear part $x^A$:
$$
T'(x) =
\begin{pmatrix}
on1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & off1 X3 & off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & on2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & off2 X5 & off2 X4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$T'(x)$ can be calculated as follows:
$$
T'(x) = (K x^A) ⊙ (A ⊘ x)\\
T'(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix} on1 X1 \\ off1 X2 X3 \\ on2 X3 \\ off2 X4 X5 \end{pmatrix} ⊙ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{X1}&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&\frac{1}{X2}&\frac{1}{X3}&0&0 \\ 0&0&\frac{1}{X3}&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&\frac{1}{X4}&\frac{1}{X5} \end{pmatrix}
$$
⊙ is the Hadamard product and ⊘ the Hadamard division.
So that:
$$
J = S ((K x^A) ⊙ (A ⊘ x)) \\
J =
\begin{pmatrix} -1&1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&-1&1 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
on1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & off1 X3 & off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & on2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & off2 X5 & off2 X4
\end{pmatrix} \\
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-on1 & off1 X3 & off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
on1 & -off1 X3 & -off1 X2 & 0 & 0\\
on1 & -off1 X3 & -off1 X2 - on2 & off2 X5 & off2 X4\\
0 & 0 & on2 & -off2 X5 & -off2 X4 \\
0 & 0 & on2 & -off2 X5 & -off2 X4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It's not clear how $(A\oslash x)$ should be interpreted in your formula, since $\oslash$ denotes elementwise division. How do you perform an elementwise operation when the first operand is a matrix and the second is a vector?
